# MonthCalendar in WPF?

Tags: wpf, monthcalendar

Is there a free class library that offers a MonthCalendar control for WPF? And is the MonthCalendar equal to if not better than the Winforms MonthCalendar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is one included in VS 2010, but there is not one built in for sure in VS 2008.

You can use the [WPF toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117), it has a nice month calendar control that should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Download the WPF Toolkit... it includes a Calendar, DatePicker, and DataGrid.  Once you add the toolkit dll to your project, you can implement the calendar like so:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Playground.Window4"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" >

    <Grid>
        <toolkit:Calendar/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```